# avcodec_encode_video2() error -1: Could not encode video packet - javacv

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg, javacv

I want to create a video (mp4) from a set of images and want to add a background sound to it. The background sound can either be recorded or a file may be browsed using a content chooser in android.
The following code creates the video when a  new audio is recorded in 3gp format. However when i browse an audio file (mp3 for example), it shows this error and the video recorded cannot be played.

the error shown is:

```
org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameRecorder$Exception: avcodec_encode_video2() error -1: Could not encode video packet. :at video_settings$Generate.doInBackground(video_settings.java:298)
```

the code at video_settings.java:298 is

```
                    recorder.record(frame2);
```

relevant code is:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {


        try {
            FrameGrabber grabber1 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(paths.get(0));
            FrameGrabber grabber2 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(backgroundSoundPath);
            Log.d("hgbj", backgroundSoundPath);
            grabber1.start();
            grabber2.start();

            FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(video, 320,
                    240, grabber2.getAudioChannels());// 320, 240
            recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4);//
            recorder.setPixelFormat(avutil.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
            recorder.setFormat("mp4");
            recorder.setFrameRate(2);
            recorder.setVideoBitrate(10 * 1024 * 1024);

            recorder.start();
            Frame frame1, frame2;
            long timeLength = grabber2.getLengthInTime();
            System.out.println("total time = " + timeLength);


            for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
                // record this frame and then record (numFrames*percentageTime[i]/100) number of frames of the audio.
                frame1 = grabber1.grabFrame();
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                recorder.setTimestamp(startTime * 1000);
                recorder.record(frame1);
                boolean first = true;
                // while current time - start time < percentage time * total time / 100: record frame2
                long temp = timeLength * percentageTime[i] / 100000 + startTime;
                while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= temp) {
                    frame2 = grabber2.grabFrame();
                    if (frame2 == null) break;
                    if (first) {
                        recorder.setTimestamp(startTime * 1000);
                        first = false;
                    }
                    recorder.record(frame2);
                }
                if (i < paths.size() - 1) {
                    grabber1.stop();
                    grabber1 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(paths.get(i + 1));
                    grabber1.start();
                }
            }
```

My question is: if its working for 3gp recorded files why isn't it working for browsed mp3 files and what should I do to make it work?
I have tried changing the codecs, frame height width, video bitrate but dont know any way to determine what bitrate etc is compatible with a given codec/format.
I am changing the content uri obtained from file browser into the real path so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use another video codec.
I myself set the video codec to AV_CODEC_ID_H264 to solve the problem.
So you might try like this:

```
recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
```